# How to Create High Quality Banner with Minimum Size In PhotoShop cs5

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i am graphic designer from last 3 months and facing a problem to create high quality banner with minimum size in kbs. When i create banner it always in MB size as you know not good for website.
I am waiting for your answer.

Regards
Shailendra Negi 
Graphic Web designer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use save for web as JPG then reduce the quality slider as low as possible without ruining the image. Can alternatively type in how many kb you want the image and it'll find the quality for you, but I find that its best to use the quality slider.

Comment: Hi Ryan, your answer was really helpful for me and please update me regular.